# Формула расчета валют?

Tags: веб-программирование, математика

В общем, хочу сделать калькулятор расчета с одной валюты в другую. Скажем, список валют будет такой: евро, доллар, рубли, гривны.

Допустим я хочу поменять рубли в гривны, то у нас получается формула такая: рубли / курс = ?
Если хочу поменять гривны в рубли, то формула получается такая: гривны * курс = ?

Как видем, у нас формулы разные. Так вот, как сделать одну идентичную формулу, чтобы рассчитать? Ведь я не буду же указывать для каждой валюты формулу.

Comment: Для каждой пары валют надо иметь, по большому счету, два значения — для покупки и для продажи. Формулы-то одинаковые, а вот значения в них подставляются разные :)

Comment: Покажите конкретный пример. Какие курсы валют у вас есть?

Answer (score 0):

Берете курс каждой валюты к рублю (к примеру, 1 гривна = 2.44 руб.) для самого рубля 1, для того чтобы перевести из одной валюты в другую умножаете сумму на изначальный курс и делите на конечный (к примеру перевод гривны в рубли: сумма * 2.44 / 1 обратно: сумма * 1 / 2.44)

Примеры:

| Из | В | Формула (сумма * курс_из / курс_в) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Доллар (90.18 руб) | Рубль | сумма * 90.18 / 1 |
| Рубль | Доллар (90.18 руб) | сумма * 1 / 90.18 |
| Доллар (90.18 руб) | Гривна(2.44руб) | сумма * 90.18 / 2.44 |
| Гривна(2.44руб) | Доллар (90.18 руб) | сумма * 2.44 / 90.18 |

Comment: У нас получается все равно формула разная. А можете пожалуйста показать как будут выглядеть формулы для всех этих валют? Я просто не могу понять, как её правильно рассчитать. А вдруг там гривны в доллары или доллары в рубли :)

Comment: @dbeuiehd добавил примеры. Вроде формула одинаковая сначала переводим в рубли потом в нужную валюту для рубля курс 1

Comment: ну вот, видите, формулы разные. Получается, мне для каждого направления нужно делать свою формулу. У вас в некоторых формулах идет сначала умножение на 1, а в других формулах идет деление на 1

Comment: @dbeuiehd просто считайте рубль за отдельную валюту и когда выбираете какие-то две валюты ищите их курс и делите курс первой на курс второй, потом умножаете на сумму для перевода.

Comment: блин, как все сложно :Д

Comment: @gord1402 Ха, а это не обязательно сработает — перегонка через промежуточную валюту. Тут могут быть самые разные варианты...

Да и сами курсы туда и обратно (покупка и продажа) в жизни разные. См. маржа, кажется, это называется. Так что все еще сложнее.

Comment: @Harry, если хотите сложностей, то надо составлять направленный граф курсов и делать по нему поиск (в ширину, в глубину, Дейкстру). Ещё надо сделать контроль циклов, вдруг найдётся цикл с доходом?

Comment: @Harry, маржа - доход с конкретного набора операций. А то что вы говорите - [спред](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8B))

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Охотно поверю, никогда не имел столько финансов, чтоб терминологией интересоваться... Слышал слово, вставил... Цикл с доходом не найдется, там тоже не дураки сидят :)